# Unexpected error when trying to run Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, packaging

This question is related to [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558246/how-to-package-to-production-my-react-website-with-webpack), I am trying to package my react app (html and javascript) and deploy it on another machine on IIS.

---

When I run `npm run build:prod`, I get an error: `index.js Line 1: Unexpected reserved word. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

---

Here is my `scripts` section in the **package.json**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build:prod": "webpack --optimize-minimize --config webpack.prod.config.js",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
```

The **webpack.prod.config.js**:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist_prod'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: "jquery", jQuery: "jquery" })
  ],
  externales: { "jquery": "jQuery", "$": 'jQuery' },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' }, // use ! to chain loaders
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' } // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
    ]
  }
};
```

and the perfectly fine **index.js** file since the error mentions it:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';

var myApp = React.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: I think you are missing a loader to transpile your ES6 and probably your JSX. Perhaps your missing babel and jsx loaders?

Comment: I think you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed I was missing one loader :

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loaders: ['babel'],
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
  },
  { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' }, // use ! to chain loaders
  { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
  { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' } // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
]
```

Thanks @Alexander O'Mara